# Error trying to import reducer from 'redux-form'

Tags: redux-form

he app was running ok, importing the reducer from redux-form and added to combine reducers, this error appears and i can't find the solution in the web.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'

import App from './components/App'
import reducers from './reducers'

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
  <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector('#root')
)


import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import authReducer from './authReducer'
import {reducer} from '../../node_modules/redux-form/lib/reducer'

export default combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  form: reducer,
})
```

withRef is removed. To access the wrapped instance, use a ref on the connected component

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem with fixing react-redux version in package.json

Changed "react-redux": "^6.0.0" to "react-redux": "^5.1.1"

Comment: Downgrading the version it's not a solution; if you look at the [changelog](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases) you can read about the breaking change that's causing the error.